# SQLAlchemy and the sql 'Use Database' command

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy and the create_engine to connect to mysql, build a database and start populating with relevant data.

edit, to preface, the database in question needs to be first created. to do this I perform the following commands

```
database_address = 'mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'
database_address = database_address.format('username',
                                           'password',
                                           'ip_address',
                                           'port')
engine = create_engine(database_address, echo=False)

Database_Name = 'DatabaseName'
engine.execute(("Create Databse {0}").format(Database_Name)
```

Following creation of the database, I try to perform a 'use' command but end up receiving the following error

```
line 3516, in _escape_identifier
    value = value.replace(self.escape_quote, self.escape_to_quote)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I traced the error to a post which stated that this occurs when using the following command in python 3

```
engine.execute("USE dbname")
```

What else needs to be included in the execute command to access the mysql database and not throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `USE` command - instead you should specify the database you wish to connect to in the `create_engine` connection url - i.e.:

```
database_address = 'mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'
database_address = database_address.format('username',
                                           'password',
                                           'ip_address',
                                           'port',
                                           'database')
engine = create_engine(database_address, echo=False)
```

The `create_engine` docs are here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#mysql

Comment: but the database hasn't been created yet. I have this setup for when the database exists but how does one go about before.

Comment: You should be using sqlalchemy to create the database via `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what to do,

Following advise from Match, I looked into SQLAlchemy and it's ability to create schema.

Found the following code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

database_address = 'mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?charset=utf8mb4'
database_address = database_address.format('username','password','address','port','DB')
engine = create_engine(database_address, echo=False)

if not database_exists(self.engine.url):
        create_database(self.engine.url)
```

So creating an engine with the Schema name identified, I can use the utility `database_exists` to see if the database does exist, if not, then create using the `create_database` function.

Comment: You shouldn't have `self.engine.url` in this context.  Just use `database_address` instead.